# Getting sheet by index causes error in vba macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying create a macro in Excel, but the following code causes error. I can't get why

```
Public Sub CreateSimpleModel()

    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) <-- Here I get the error

End Sub
```

The the message box appears it shows that there are sheets in workbook. The error `object variable or with block not set` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "Set" if you want reference Workbook

```
Public Sub CreateSimpleModel()

    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

End Sub
```